# Omit blank lines when trimming fields with views

Tags: views, entities

I have made a views gets the body field and select:
 
    Formatter ->summary or trimmed

but the field have blank lines which calculated in the length so I may get empty.

Despite selecting  Remove whitespace but still count the blank lines as it is full of text and so I get empty preview.

Please help .

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar problem in the past, especially when making the summary trimmed to a shorter length.

When it tries to truncate certain tags like tables or images that can be quite long - and the number of characters you allow is reached before the table/image has been fully parsed, you can end up with a blank summary.

What I do is that I strip certain HTML tags from my fields that are trimmed to only display paragraphs, etc - not images and/or tables.

Just click on the field to set up the new configuration, and you'll find the option in the 'Rewrite Results' section:

[image]

Let us know if this works!